# use of @property to generate random strings from another class

Tags: python, properties

I have a class which lets say prints strings number of times:

```
class ABC:
    def print_times(self, value):
        for i in range(4):
            print(value)
```

I want to be able to pass value as a string or as a property of another class to generate for example random string.

```
import random
import string

class RS:
    def __init__(self, length: int):
        self.N = length

    @property
    def value(self):
        return ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits)
                      for _ in range(self.N))
```

when calling

```
a = ABC()
rs = RS(10)
a.print_times(rs.value)
```

I always get the same value of a property when I want it to be different. If i call it directly, I get random results every time... Why is it happening so?

```
rs = RS(10)
print(rs.value)
print(rs.value)
```

Comment: "rs.value" generates and returns **one** string which is given to "print_times" and printed four times there.

Comment: `a.print_times(rs.value)` is the same as `value = rs.value`, followed by `a.print_times(value)`. The string is generated only once.

Comment: You can pass `RS` instance and then call value inside the print function

Answer (score 2):

> I always get the same value of a property when I want it to be different. If I call it directly, I get random results every time... Why is it happening so?

Because you are calling function once and printing value 4 times. More precisely, each time you call rs.value you get different result, and you are calling once and printing that value 4 times.
Below code might help you,

```py
import random
import string

class RS:
    def __init__(self, length: int):
        self.N = length

    @property
    def value(self):
        return ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits)
                      for _ in range(self.N))
                      
class ABC:
    def __init__(self, length: int):
        self.N = length
        self.rs = RS(self.N)
        
    def print_times(self):
        for i in range(4):
            print(self.rs.value)
                    
a = ABC(10)
a.print_times()
```

Comment: It is important to be able to pass parameter what to print_times. Would it be pythonic to change RS.value property to method and in ABC.print_times check if value parameter is a method or value- inspect.ismethod(value)?

Comment: I still doubt, then why do you need two class, you can directly create value method inside `ABC` class, call inside print_times. It makes more easier than this. Of course, it would be pythonic. How does it differ?